# F# Javascript quotations

Tags: f#

is anyone working in F# with quotations for javascript? I am thinking of a project and would like some input.

Comment: I think you might need to clarify your question.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://websharper.com/extensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean translating F# code to JavaScript using quotations?  There was a question about that recently:

- [F#/JavaScript tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371198/f-javascript-tool)

If you wanted to work on this or something related, the **FSharp.JavaScript** is open source (see [GitHub](https://github.com/jgreene/FSharp.Javascript)), so it could be a great starting point. Last time I checked, the project looked quite good, but there is always space for some improvements (or related projects). I would be quite interested to see how this would integrate with other F# web development frameworks (for example with [Bistro](http://www.bistroframework.org/index.php?title=FSharp)).

My **F# Web Tools** (mentioned in the answer, now defunct) had (I think) some interesting ideas on integrating the client-side with the server-side. This is something that's not currently done in other projects (AFAIK) and could be an interesting thing to explore. (I wrote some articles on how that worked, see [for example this](http://tomasp.net/articles/fswebtools-intro.aspx)).

Comment: I actually integrated it fairly heavily with the asp.net mvc framework using my FSharp.Javascript.Mvc project (see [GitHub](https://github.com/jgreene/FSharp.Javascript.Mvc)).  This provides an easy way to access your F# modules client side and (what I believe to be) the most powerful validation framework out there.  You can read about it more [here](http://justsimplecode.com/archive/2010/11/15/fsharp.javascript.mvc-a-new-validation-framework-for-f-and-asp.net.aspx).

Comment: @justin: Thanks for the link. That looks fantastic, this is what I was hoping for :-). I'll have to take a closer look at the project - but I think you're doing a great job.